# Should be very trivial, why i cannot change the value of my vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   double rdm_num;
   cout << "Please input a random number to be mutiplied:";
   cin >> rdm_num;

   vector<int> v;
   for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) {
      v.push_back(i);
   }

   cout << "done with initilization"<<endl;

   for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) {
      v[i] = v[i] * 2;
   }

   for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int i) -> int {
      return i*rdm_num; 
   });

   for (auto it = v.begin(); it<v.end(); it++) {
      cout << *it << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I'm learning lambda function recently, please refer to my code above, I encounter two problems with the code.

Problem 1: I cannot re-value my vectors. The following line will give me a running-time error 1236 vector subscript out of range:

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) v[i] = v[i] * 2;
```

Problem 2: no matter what i do, my iterator only output one value 5.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo `for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`

Comment: Also note that you will have 6 elements not 5.  If you need 5 then you need `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

Three problems:

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) v.push_back(i);
-------------^
```

This only pushes '5' back onto the vector, because you start at 5.

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) v[i] = v[i] * 2;
-------------^
```

You only pushed one element onto the vector, but this loop tries to update the 5th element. Bruce Willis would be sad.

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int i) -> int {return i*rdm_num; });
----------------------------------------^^^^^^--^^^^^^
```

for_each does not expect or process a return value. Instead you need to receive your lambda-function parameter by reference so you can modify it:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [rdm_num](int& i) { i = i*rdm_num; });
                                       ^^^^
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double rdm_num;
    cout << "Please input a random number to be mutiplied:";
    cin >> rdm_num;

    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v.push_back(i);

    cout << "done with initilization"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v[i] = v[i] * 2;

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [rdm_num](int& i) { i *= rdm_num; });
    /* ---------------------------^^^^^^^
     * I prefer to name my captured values; using '&' or '=' is fine tho,
     * as long as you know what you are doing */

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it<v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/tpJSWW

Comment: Needed a 'multipush' to get that 5th element

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int &i) { i *= rdm_num; });
                                     ^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no sense in the returning value of the lambda-expression because it is not used. And the element of the vector has to be passed by reference.